# Using PyTransitions State Machine to force a callback during State Machine intialization

Tags: python, pytransitions

I have written a state machine for a pool controller, but I am struggling with something that is noted in the documentation about forcing the on_enter method to fire off when I initialize the model.    The documentation says:

> "Note that `on_enter_«state name»` callback will not fire when a Machine is first initialized. For example if you have an `on_enter_A()` callback defined, and initialize the Machine with `initial='A'`, `on_enter_A()` will not be fired until the next time you enter state A. (If you need to make sure `on_enter_A()` fires at initialization, you can simply create a dummy initial state and then explicitly call `to_A()` inside the `__init__` method.)"

But I am not sure where I need to call this out....I create a Class called `Pool_Controller`, then create an instance of `Pool_Controller` like this

```
MyController=Pool_Controller
```

And then I create the state machine like this

```
machine = Machine(MyController, states=states, transitions, initial='dummy_state')
```

Where do I need to put the `to_initial_state()` to get the dummy_state immediately jump to my initial_state so that `on_enter_initial_state` will execute when the model intializes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly call `to_initial_state` after the controller (the model) has been decorated (added to the machine). I'd suggest an approach where the machine is instantiated first and passed to the model's constructor:

```py
from transitions import Machine

class PoolController:

    def __init__(self, machine):
        machine.add_model(self)
        self.to_initial_state()

# we will add the model later (in the model constructor)
machine = Machine(model=None, states=['dummy_state', 'initial_state'], initial='dummy_state')
controller = PoolController(machine)
assert controller.is_initial_state()
```